# What complexity does this 'how many ways to climb' algorithm have?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

I have a solution to the following problem:

> Given a stairway of $n$ stairs, which you can climb from $1$ to $m$ at the
>   time ($1 \leq m \leq n$), return all the ways you can climb the stairway.
>
> E.g. for $n = 3$, $m = 2$, the possible ways to climb are $[2,1], [1,2], [1,1,1]$

```js
// outputs all the ways to react total using steps from 1 to max;
// returns the count of iterations
function permut(total, max, out) {
  // store unfinished tracks; start with an initial track
  let iter = [{ val: [], sum: 0 }];
  let count = 0;

  // take the next track until there are none
  for (let i of iter) {
    for (let s = 1; s <= max; s++) {
      // append step value to the current track
      // assume constant complexity
      let val = [...i.val, s];
      let sum = i.sum + s;

      count++;

      if (sum === total) {
        // we've reached the top;
        // do not expand current track further
        out(val);
        break;
      }

      // add an unfinished track and start over
      iter.push({ val, sum });
    }
  }

  return count;
}
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-cdn-7idu9

However, I can't figure out the time complexity relatively to $m$ and $n$. For $m = 1$ the number of iterations is $n$, for $m = n$ it's $2^n - 1$.

Also, is there a canonical solution to this problem?

Comment: So what if sum > total?

Comment: Shouldn't happen if valid inputs are provided

Comment: Can you express your algorithm in concise language-independent pseudocode, so we don't have to understand Javascript syntax or the meaning of things like `iter.push()` or `[...i.val, s]`?

Comment: @D.W. I don't think I can do any better in pseudocode, but I added few more comments

Comment: But what is the cost of `[...i.val, s]`? Linear? Constant? Depends on the compiler?

Comment: @PeterTaylor good question; let's assume linear

Answer (score 4):

The solution is the recursive formula:

$S[k] = \sum_{i=1}^mS[k-i]$

For $m=2$ this is the Fibonacci sequence, and the way to program it is with dynamic programming. The complexity of the dynamic programming is $O(m \cdot n)$.

Consider the last step before reaching step $k$, the number of ways to reach $k$ when the last step is $i$, is equal to the number of steps to reach $S[k-i]$

Comment: Note that if $m$ is small and $n$ is large you might want to consider rewriting this in matrix form and then use fast exponentiation, to get a runtime of $O(m^3\log(n))$, or even $O(m^{2.376}\log(n))$ if you use the Coppersmith–Winograd algorithm for the matrix multiplication steps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This assumes [] is only calculated once per , correct? What complexity it would be otherwise?

Comment: Yes, it assumes that the calculation is done once, otherwise, with recursion (without memory) it will be $O(m^n)$ since every step makes m recursion calls

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the so-called partition function (with some constraints on the addends). A simple upper bound is the number of solutions (and thus for the runtime since you generate all of them). For the unconstrained case this is $e^{c\sqrt n}$ as per Siegel with c=$\pi\sqrt\frac{2}{3}$.

There are several specialised formulas with tighter bounds depending on certain contraints (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory) for lots of them) but generally the dominating term will be in the order of $n!$.

In (de Azevedo Pribitkin, W. Ramanujan J (2009) 18: 113. https://doi.org/10.1007/s11139-007-9022-z) an upper bound of $\frac{e^{c\sqrt n}} {n^{3/4}}$ is given. Without further assumptions about $m$ that is probably the best bound we can give while keeping the formula simple.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So where is  in this formula?

Comment: As I said, you need further assumptions about  to decrease the bound. If for instance $m$ would be 3 you could lower the bound to $\frac{n^2}{3!} + O(n)$. (This is from the Asymptotics part of the wiki page.) The exponent $2$ coming from $m-1$.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the question is about time complexity without DP. I read somewhere that it was mentioned the complexity is $\mathcal O(m^n)$ but there is a much tighter bound that I will derive below.

Based on the recursion relation we get

$$
T(n) =  \sum_{i=1}^m T(n-i) + m
$$

where I have included the time for adding the results of the recursive calls.

Now it seems intuitive that the time complexity is exponential so lets take as an ansatz $T(n) \sim x^n$ and then we get

$$
x^n = x^{n}(x^{-1} + x^{-2} + ... +x^{-m}) + m
$$

At this point we can drop the term linear in m *assuming* that we will get $x>1$. If we do not get the same our assumption will be unjustified but we will see below that this is indeed what we get.

On summing the series on the RHS we get

$$
1= \frac{1-x^{-m-1}}{1-x^{-1}}-1 
$$

which can be further simplified to give

$$
\frac{x^m(x-2)+1}{x-1}=0
$$

This solution asymptotes to 2 from below. Thus the tighter bound is $\mathcal O(2^m)$.